# Problem in Display TextView

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I have Done One Layout in My Application Where i have TextView and in that i have to shown the Paragraph. now i9 have set all the contain in to the XML file as below code. But it cant seen the Whole text and the last line of the paragraph is cut. . . What i have to do for it ??
Help me. . .  Thanks.
Code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >
            <Button
                android:layout_height="35dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="1973"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:background="@drawable/histry"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_height="100dip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12px"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:singleLine="false"

                    android:text="Tony Collier, a cook at the Grandview Foundation in Pasadena, begins collecting and distributing food. Collier receives more food donations from local businesses than anticipated and he shares the food with other organizations helping the hungry.  Collier begins the first search for a larger facility by moving the small operation into a two-car garage."/>

        </LinearLayout>     

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use 100dip height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="1973"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:background="#ffff" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:text="Tony Collier, a cook at the Grandview Foundation in Pasadena, begins collecting and distributing food. Collier receives more food donations from local businesses than anticipated and he shares the food with other organizations helping the hungry.  Collier begins the first search for a larger facility by moving the small operation into a two-car garage." android:textSize="12dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>     

</LinearLayout>
```

***Check this***

i tried what you needed its just simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffff" android:background="@drawable/icon" android:text="1222"></Button>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text  Tony Collier, a cook at the Grandview Foundation in Pasadena, begins collecting and distributing food. Collier receives more food donations from local businesses than anticipated and he shares the food with other organizations helping the hungry.  Collier begins the first search for a larger facility by moving the small operation into a two-car garage."></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for reply and It works.. But i have set the Button Background as one Image. When i put that then the text is cut..  What can i do for it ??

Comment: set button and textview and both width ="FillParent" and give them weight 1 and adjust the weight accordingly it will wwork

Comment: Hey Thanks alot. . . I will try for it. . . can u explain in normal way what is the basically use of weight in layout ???

Answer (score 0):

set Freezes Text="true" property of TextView..

Comment: But i want to Show is shown regular not at the center. .  i have already tried it. .  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have that one also but still it seems to cutting text. . . Anyway Thanks for the reply

Comment: u WelCome Just try this one also Freezes Text="true"

Comment: Means ? i didnt get u properly. . . I have to set text ="true" isen't it ??

Comment: just go in xml file n check is there any property of Freezes..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set some attributes for your TextView.

Ex.
layout_width
maxLines
minLines

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html.